# Search a specific word covered with special charecter

Tags: php

> $x = "My name is {{myname}}.And i am a good {{boy}}"  .i want to get myname and boy enclosed with {{}}.I have tried many php functions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, amiya! Unfortunately your question is unsuitable for this site. We'll be happy to help you with the specific problems you encounter while programming your stuff, but you have to **add more details** and **show more relevant code.** **You can edit questions using ‘edit’ link below tags list.** Please see **“[How do ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”** for more information.

Comment: @amiya, do you want to replace that words with another values ?

Comment: No i want the values that written inside {{ }}